# What is the highest elixir collector level for town hall 5?

Tags: clash-of-clans

What is the highest elixir collector level for town hall 5? I have looked it up but couldn't find it

Comment: [this](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Elixir_Collector) was the very first link of a google search *"highest elixir collector level for town hall 5"*

Answer (score 2):

The highest elixir collector level for town hall 5 is level 10!

http://www.gamatrix.com/clash-of-clans/wiki?page=other%2FWikiCamp5

*Happy Clashing!*